# NSIndexPath incrementing values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to populate an OutlineView with the contents of a XML file.

I'd like to create and manage the values inside a NSIndexPath while cocoa parses the document.
NSIndexPath has methods to add and remove indexes, but I need to increment/decrement the values in each index:

[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[0, 2]

and so on...

how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSIndexPath isn't mutable, so you'll have to create a new index path every time. Probably the most efficient way would be to use `length`, `getIndexes:`, and `initWithIndexes:length:` messages, plus the `realloc` function to grow/shrink the buffer.

Don't forget to `release` the old index path after getting its indexes into the buffer and before `alloc`king and `init`ing (`WithIndexes:length:`) the new one, and to `free` the buffer when you're done. (Also don't forget that `realloc` frees the old buffer for you, so you only need to `free` the last buffer.)

Comment: is there no other alternative? Why count so much on NSIndexPath, if it's not manageable?

Comment: LolaRun: You could maintain a C array of indexes. Then you could modify indexes in the array at will, creating an NSIndexPath from the array when you need one. (Easiest if you know how big the array will need to be. Otherwise, you'll need to reallocate it when you need to make it bigger.) The reason to create NSIndexPaths is some things need them, such as UITableViews in Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with @LolaRun -- we're Cocoa babies, we don't want no realloc. So, try something like this:

```
NSUInteger newIndexes[] = {0,1};
NSUInteger len = sizeof(newIndexes)/sizeof(NSUInteger); //sorry!
NSIndexPath *baseIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:newIndexes 
                                                        length:len];
NSUInteger i;
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [baseIndexPath indexPathByAddingIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"newIndexPath = %@", newIndexPath);
}
```

Or you may want to increment an existing indexPath (the first line instantiates an indexPath with the newIndexes array from the example above):

```
NSIndexPath *someIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:newIndexes 
                                                        length:len];
    NSUInteger newIndexes2[[someIndexPath length]];
    [someIndexPath getIndexes:newIndexes2];

    NSUInteger len2 = sizeof(newIndexes2)/sizeof(NSUInteger);
    NSIndexPath *baseIndexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:newIndexes2 
                                                             length:len2];
    NSUInteger ii;
    NSInteger start = [someIndexPath indexAtPosition:[someIndexPath length] -1];
    for (ii=start; ii<10; ii++) {
        NSIndexPath *newIndexPath2 = [baseIndexPath2 indexPathByAddingIndex:ii];
        NSLog(@"newIndexPath2 = %@", newIndexPath2);
    }
```

Note that the first example will create children of the original path 0.1, while the second one creates siblings. Mix 'n match as you like.