# Is It Possible To Adjust indexPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Under a table view delegate, `indexPath` is sent. Is it possible to assign this to a local variable and then adjust it? I didn't see anything in the class reference docs.

What I'm trying to do is add 1 to the `indexPath.row`.

This code doesn't work, but I'm putting it here to get the basic idea across.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *tempIndex;
    tempIndex = indexPath;
    tempIndex.row = tempIndex.row + 1;
//etc...
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: NSIndexPath is immutable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331659/nsindexpath-incrementing-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get another NSIndexPath by calling

```
NSIndexPath *tempIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section];
```

Although I don't understand what you mean by "adjusting" it. Typically, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you don't work with other paths/cells that the one which is asked for.